# Non-bulk upload to app datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a very large SQLite database. Large for a SQLite db, anyway: 1.13 GB. I have tried to bulk-upload it, except that I was not able to dump the database to CSV. I have tried several times, and have basically given up.

The more practical approach seemed to adapt the code I found at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/#Python_Datastore_API to upload to the datastore one record at a time. Let it run overnight. That sort of thing.

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        App Data Store
# Purpose:      Move chess database to the app engine datastore
#               from c:\\PGNSDB
#               Comcast is the worst company in the world
# Created:     22/06/2013
# Copyright:   (c) Administrator 2013
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
import sqlite3
import google
import logging

class game(db.Model):
        Event = db.StringProperty(required=False)
        Site = db.StringProperty(required=False)
        EventDate = db.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=True)
        Round = db.StringProperty(required=False)
        White = db.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
        Black = db.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
        Result = db.StringProperty(required=True,
                            choices=set(["1-0","0-1","1/2-1/2"]), indexed=True)
        ECO = db.StringProperty(required=False)
        WhiteELO = db.StringProperty(required=False)
        BlackELO = db.StringProperty(required=False)
        PlyCount = db.StringProperty(required=False)
        PGN = db.StringProperty(required=True)
        email = db.StringProperty()

def main():
    logging.info('Beginning upload')
    conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\PGNSDB')
    c = conn.cursor()
    games = c.execute("select Event, Site, Date, Round, White, Black, Result, ECO, WhiteELO, BlackELO, PGN from games")

    logging.info('Local database is now open on C drive.')

    for agame in games:
        logging.info('Uploading a PGN.')
        thisgame = game(Event = agame[0],
                        Site = agame[1],
                        EventDate = agame[2],
                        Round = agame[3],
                        White = agame[4],
                        Black = agame[5],
                        Result = agame[6],
                        ECO = agame[7],
                        WhiteELO = agame[8],
                        BlackELO = agame[9],
                        PGN = agame[10],
                        #email = users.get_current_user().email())
                        email = "xxx@gmail.com")
        logging.info('About to put.')
        thisgame.put()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So I ran it in the Google App Engine Launcher with the following app.yaml:

```
application: pgnhelper
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: home.app

- url: /index\.html
  script: home.app

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.app
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: not_found.app

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

... and have the following logged output:

```
2013-07-01 21:40:59 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', u'C:\\Code\\uploadpgns']"
INFO     2013-07-01 21:41:06,479 devappserver2.py:528] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-07-01 21:41:06,530 api_server.py:314] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
WARNING  2013-07-01 21:41:06,546 simple_search_stub.py:955] Could not read search indexes from c:\users\jj\appdata\local\temp\appengine.pgnhelper\search_indexes
INFO     2013-07-01 21:41:06,612 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http : //XXX:58254
INFO     2013-07-01 21:41:06,621 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http : //XXX:8080
INFO     2013-07-01 21:41:06,627 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http : //XXX:8000
INFO     2013-07-01 21:46:46,724 api_server.py:509] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-07-01 21:46:46,724 api_server.py:512] Saving search indexes
2013-07-01 21:46:46 (Process exited with code 0)

2013-07-01 21:53:53 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', u'C:\\Code\\uploadpgns']"
INFO     2013-07-01 21:53:54,956 devappserver2.py:528] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-07-01 21:53:54,963 api_server.py:314] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-07-01 21:53:54,974 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http : //XXX:58311
INFO     2013-07-01 21:53:54,980 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http : //XXX:8080
INFO     2013-07-01 21:53:54,984 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http : //XXX:8000
ERROR    2013-07-02 01:54:46,207 wsgi.py:219] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler

    handler = __import__(path[0])

ImportError: No module named home

INFO     2013-07-01 21:54:46,223 server.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2013-07-02 01:54:46,325 wsgi.py:219] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler

    handler = __import__(path[0])

ImportError: No module named not_found

INFO     2013-07-01 21:54:46,332 server.py:593] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

... Where XXX symbolizes the link to localhost ... I think I'm missing something pretty fundamental about this WSGI. And the module named not_found? Can't find it!

The example I found mentions nothing about a gateway interface. How do I incorporate one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the dev appserver (or local app.yaml etc) at all.

Put your code into a module (no handlers etc as you have done) and import it into the remote_api_shell.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api

You then can import anything you want as you are not running in the sandbox and you are talking directly to the appengine datastore.

You can also speed things up by batching the put of your game objects. Say store every 100 in a list, and then do a db.put(the_list)

Comment: Still kind of a python noob, can I ask another question? My file was called upload.py, and I imported it ("import upload") and typed "main()", but it didn't recognize it. Ended up pasting the code line by line to get it to execute in the shell... What's the right way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your current working directory is the location of your upload.py when you run the remote_api_shell.